# Change Div margin with screen resize

Tags: html, css, resize, margin

I am creating a navigation menu with a background.
See the website http://lolraffle.com

I have the following HTML

```
<nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="home">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And this CSS to make the nav hover exactly over the menu background.

```
nav#menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -67px;
  margin-left: 678px;
}
```

Now the problem is that when I resize the screen, the menu does not move along the page as it is defined in pixels.

I tried to convert the pixels to percentages but it is still not working

```
nav#menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: 51.3%;
}
```

It is still not working.

Is there a quick and easy way to stick my navigation menu on that place, and **keep it there when the screen resizes**?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Usage of ViewPort meta tag

Use meta tag for the viewport as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

### Usage of percentage values

Then, if you use percentage you will get the desired result. For example when you use this css

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The browser wil automatically change the widths and heights of the elements, depending on the currect screen size!

### CSS3 Media Query

Third thing to do is to use CSS3 Media Query, how?

You can check the currect screen size, and then change the CSS properties. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  /* here you will write the properties which will be visible 
   * on the devices which have max width of 900px
   */
}
```

Then when you will set margins, you will see the changes there.

### Change the margins

Other way to do this, is to use `top` `left` instead of `margin-top` and `margin-left`.

Like this:

```
nav#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: -67px;
  left: 678px;
}
```

### Use float instead of margins

An easy way would be to make it float to the right, as:

```
nav#menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
```

This way, you will get the navigation on the right side. And you won't have to worry about the margins either!

#### Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong!

1. Put the image as background image and not as an actual `<img>` tag.
2. Don't use position: absolute, instead just float the nav to the right.

Comment: I know it is a kinda strange solution to use the <img> tag, but othwerise the menu-wrapper background doesn't resize properly.

Comment: that is because you are floating all the `li`, put `overflow:hidden` on the `ul` and you should be good. And i suggest you learn some css basics before moving on